# SSH connection closed after SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST

Tags: ssh, centos, logging, sshd, remote-connection

My SSH connection is being closed just after this message:

```
debug1: ssh_dss_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
Connection closed by x.x.x.x
```

The weird part is that `sshd` seems to send keys as well. How can I proceed to find out what is happening (I cannot access the server, only request a reset). What are my options after a reset (which logs are interesting to trace the cause?)

Comment: can you provide server logs?

Comment: @Jakuje which would be useful?

Comment: some error log from `sshd`. Not sure where is it on your distro. Or more verbose log.